# Calling a method from an external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a external JS function defined below held within test.js

```
function InvokeSupport(ID, TimeStamp, Hash) {

    var sUrl = '<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"] %>' + "?uid=" + ID + "&t=" + TimeStamp + "&hash=" + Hash;

    window.open(sUrl, "Support", null, false);   
}
```

On my asp.net page I have the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../scripts/test.js"></script>

<div class="User">
    <span class="UserName"><button type="submit" title="Help!" onclick="InvokeSupport()" class="Class1"></button> </span>
</div>
```

THE PROBLEM

The InvokeSupport function is coming back as undefined and fails to work unless I place the function on the ASP.net page where it works. The link to the javascript file is right as I have other files in the same repository working fine.

Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: try onclick="JavaScript:return InvokeSupport();" Also notice that you are not passing parameters but you are using them to construct your URL that could again give you undefined error for those parameters.

Comment: You did't pass any arguments to the function

Comment: Apologies I am passing parameters I just forgot to include them there. This wouldnt return an undefined argument though. Ive tried the JavaScript return and this doest work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using ASP.NET script tags in external js file?

Pass the data from configuration as and additional parameter to javascript function.

Also, you can use Firebug and Chrome devTools which can show you a place of error occured

Comment: Thank you :) I was surprised you couldn't use ASP.Net script tags in an external js file but I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
function InvokeSupport(url, ID, TimeStamp, Hash) {

    var sUrl = url + "?uid=" + ID + "&t=" + TimeStamp + "&hash=" + Hash;

    window.open(sUrl, "Support", null, false);   
}


<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../scripts/test.js"></script>

<div class="User">
    <span class="UserName"><button type="submit" title="Help!" onclick="InvokeSupport('<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"] %>',1,2,3)" class="Class1"></button> </span>
</div>
```